# Having an Angular $interval running independent of controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have different pages on may application which have their own controllers. One of them has an $interval function, let's say a timer. Click on a button will start this interval function, which updates itself every second. What i want to have is, i want to be able to **go to any other page** in my application (calling different controllers), but **i want my interval to continue running** until i stop it explicitly from the first controller. A *rootScope interval* so to speak. How can i do it?

EDIT: Thanks to Chris and Patrick i now have a simple Service, looks like this:

```
  .service('TimerService', function($interval) {
    var promise;
    var timerSeconds = 0;

    this.start = function () {
      promise = $interval(function () {
        timerSeconds++;
      }, 1000);
    };

    this.stop = function () {
      promise.cancel(interval);
      timerSeconds = 0;
    };

    this.getTimer = function() {
      return timerSeconds;
    }
  })
```

I store also my current value (timerSeconds) in this service. But how can i sync this value to my controller? The service increments the timerSeconds, and at the beginning of my controller i read it from this service through its getTimer() function, but it clearly will not be updated on my controller. **How can i sync this service attribute with my local attribute?**

EDIT:

when i define my service attribute as an object and the timerSeconds as number inside that object (it seems primitives cannot be synced):

```
var timer = {seconds : 0};

this.getTimer = function() {
  return timer;
}
```

and get this object from my controller through that getter:

```
vm.timer = TimerService.getTimer();
```

they are all in sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bother adding it to $rootScope. Use a service that can be used anywhere in the app. Here is a singleton timer that can start and stop. Define the intervalTimeout in the service itself, or if you want to be really flexible, do so in a provider (probably overkill for this example).

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])

.service('AppCallback', function ($interval) {
    var states = states = {
        PENDING: 0,
        STARTED: 1
    }, intervalTimeout = 3000, // Set this
    interval;

    this.states = states;
  
    this.state = states.PENDING;
    this.start = function (callback) {
        if (this.state !== states.PENDING) {
            return;
        }

        interval = $interval(callback, intervalTimeout);
        this.state = states.STARTED;
    }

    this.stop = function () {
        if (this.state !== states.STARTED) {
            return;
        }
        $interval.cancel(interval);
        this.state = states.PENDING;
    };
})

.controller('MainController', function ($scope, AppCallback) {
  var vm = {},
      count = 0;
  
  vm.toggle = function toggle() {
    if (AppCallback.state === AppCallback.states.PENDING) {
      AppCallback.start(function () {
        vm.data = 'Ticked ' + (++count) + ' times.';
      });
     } else {
       AppCallback.stop();
     }
  };
  
  
  $scope.vm = vm;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController">
  {{vm.data}}
  <br />
  <button ng-click="vm.toggle()">Toggle</button>
</div>
```

Comment: So the service is running updating this data object in your controller, but what happens if you change your controller and call it again? your data and count objects will be lost since they are defined in your controller. . Or do i miss sth?

Comment: I have tried to add the data object to rootScope and read it from there. It kind of works, but it is not so nice always to synchronise vm and rootScope Do you have any other suggestion?.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to share any data between controllers the correct way is to use a service.

I would then create a service that allows you to stop and start this timer / interval.

The initial controller would kick this off and it would continue to "tick" forever until it is stopped.

Comment: And should i keep my timer object (the number which will always be incremented by interval) in rootScope?

Comment: Use a factory to store that number.

Comment: Yes, as @Rorschach120 suggests put that in your service / factory as that is some information you want to share between controllers